# Windows Forms application in tray not terminating process after exit

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I am using windows forms application, which runs from system tray. In ContextMenuStrip I have an Exit icon, which should be terminating my process, but it doesn't.

My process stays in task manager. So, if I run (and terminate) the applicaiton several times, then I have several processes in task manager, although none of them is reachable any more.

My code for exiting application is simple:

```
void exitOnClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   _notifyIcon.Visible = false;
    Application.Exit();
}
```

I've checked with debugger - this code is triggered when I press Exit. Notify icon dissapears, but process remains in task manager. Also, if any of win forms are open, they are closed.

Comment: That means you're running some Foreground thread which has not been killed\

Comment: Does every project in solution uses it's own thread? I use several projects in solution. Can this be the reason?

Comment: No, Not like that. I hope you create thread explicitly using `new Thread`

Comment: Other Winforms are getting closed? Are you sure is that what you mean?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - no, I don't explicitly create and threads. Should I be doing like that? Explicitly create new thread and then killing it? I've never done this before and it's true also that it's the first time that I am experiencing problems like this.

Comment: @Sangram - yes, win forms (if opened) are getting closed. Of course they must close, but I would also like to kill the process, so it doesn't stay in task manager.

Comment: Am afraid, That could be the only reason it can happen. Are you using any 3rd party libraries.? May be that can create threads?

Comment: I use only libraries that I've created (DL class library). 3rd party libraries - can you explain what you mean exactly with that?

Comment: After closing your form you can pause the execution with pause button in visual studio and see where is the debugger showing the execution point. That will help you

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [Environment.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) static method. This method:

> ... terminates an application immediately, even if other threads are
>   running.

But it's better to find a code that is still running, as you was told above.